# Recover previous Jenkins build configuration

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to recover a Jenkins build configuration from a previous build?

In order to access the Jenkins server I use I need to open an SOCKS proxy. I went to submit a modification to the configuration but the SOCKS tunnel had closed so I reconnected it. Jenkins/my browser displayed an error saying the reload failed and do I want to resubmit the POST request. I said yes and instead of submitting the changes to the configuration I wanted it submitted a blank body.

So now the configuration for my build is completely empty and I'm annoyed.

I tried checking online for solutions and didn't see any way to extract the configuration from a previous build

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that might have saved you is a backup ( or OS backup ?). There are various - [Backup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/backup), [ThinBackup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/thinBackup), [Periodic Backup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/periodicbackup), [SCM Sync Configuration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scm-sync-configuration) and others, but no Time Machine or D'oh! plugin that I know of.

Install the [Job Configuration History](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jobConfigHistory) and at least you'll quickly protected for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using rebuild plugin.

```
1. Install rebuild plugin.
2. select the build that you want to rebuild and press rebuild.
```

[image]